# XCode 6 GM: linker error when building for device (Metal not found)

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to build my project in XCode 6 GM for device (base SDK version is 7.1), and I get linker error:

```
ld: framework not found Metal for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The same project builds perfectly in XCode 5 without any changes in project settings. (Also, build in XCode 6 for *simulator* succeeds.)

I'm building with SDK 7.1, why is XCode 6 trying to link to Metal anyway?

Comment: Cleaning the project fixed it for me.

Comment: Did you mean with a 7.1 deployment target against the 8.0 SDK?  Xcode 6 does not have the 7.1 SDK.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia no, I meant 7.1 SDK. I copied it from XCode 5 directory.

Comment: might be you are using third party sdk. solution of this problem is, you need to remove your third party sdk and integrate one by one. after integration of each sdk you need to build code to check metal error exist or not.

Answer (score 9):

Having the same problem.  I am able to build the app fine in Xcode 6 pointed to the simulator or a phone, but when archiving I get this error.   I am using the iOS 7.1 SDK.

I am using cocoapods and found that I can fix the problem by either **setting the 'Link Frameworks Automatically' to NO for the pods project, or by archiving while there is a device plugged in and the scheme is targeted to a device not just 'iOS Device.'**

This is a problem caused by Xcode 6's default project build settings.

Edit: Here is another explanation of this solution: http://www.appsee.com/blog/dev/xcode-new-link-frameworks-automatically-fix-framework-not-found-metal-for-architecture-armv7

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: It does answer the question @MrTux... there's a solution given but the OP would still like a better one if available.

Comment: I have since put cocoapods under version control and just set the Link Frameworks Automatically to NO and committed it.  My team hasn't had any problems since and my Jenkins server is happy too.

Comment: The 'archive while having a device plugged in' option worked for me, also a cocoapods user. It probably depends on the pods themselves. For example, before I was using DBCamera, setting `Link Frameworks Automatically` to `NO` as mentioned above worked well. But since DBCamera has a dependency on GPUImage, for which the CPUImage target's `Link Frameworks Automatically` is set to `${PODS_GPUIMAGE_CLANG_MODULES_AUTOLINK}`, I suspect that's why I can't set it to `NO`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a code base building fine iOS 8.0 SDK (Xcode 6.0.1) and having this issue with iOS 7.1 SDK (though in Xcode 5.1.1). There seem to be a lot of different project having this problem. See [here](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/66) for more details.

What fixed the issue for me was going to my targets 'Build Phase'-settings, 'Link Binary with Libraries' and there removing and re-adding the CoreVideo.framework, 'Product > Clean', a finally the 'Product > Run'.

Answer (score -1):

Using the iOS 7.1 SDK with Xcode 6 is not a supported configuration.  The linker is behaving correctly here.  The 7.1 SDK doesn't contain Metal.framework to link against, and you have requested to link against Metal.framework.  You need to use the iOS 8.0 SDK or later to use Metal.framework.

Comment: The log you provided clearly states otherwise.  I suggest using the iOS 8 SDK as that is the only supported iOS SDK for use with Xcode 6.  Then look at your Xcode project's target's build phases to see what is bringing in Metal.framework.

Comment: BS. You can drop the 7.1 SDK in Xcode 6, for the sake of not having two Xcode versions on your pc.

Comment: @Rick ... Yes, you can do that, and some things may continue to work, but it is not a supported configuration.